# Loading only first frame of video

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have an application that retrieve videos from mediafire. The first frame of the video is shown and clicking on the image takes you to a video page that plays that specific vide.

```
<a href <%=@video_page_link%>>
     <video>
          <source src = <%=video_link%>>
     </video>
</a>
```

The problem is, there are around 20-30 videos on the page and it takes a lot of time to load each video. As a result, the application is very slow. I tried using stream io FFMPEG gem to extract an image from each video and then show the image instead in the link but it is even more slow.

Is there a way if I can quickly grab only the first frame of the video and then show it? or just load the video s first frame instead of loading the whole video? I don't really need to load the whole video I just need a video poster that can be clicked to go to the video page.

I can use the image of the video as a hyperlink but that would require me to take a screenshot of each video before uploading it and then store it somewhere which I don't want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the video_tag helper to render a video in your view. The video_tag helper will automatically pick the right video based on the browser's capabilities. <%= video_tag "video.mp4" %> You can also specify additional options that control how the video is rendered. For example, you can automatically start playing the video when it's loaded <%= video_tag "video.mp4", autoplay true %> You can also use the video_tag helper to embed a video in an HTML5-based email. To do this, set the email option to true <%= video_tag "video.mp4", email true %>

Comment: My issue is not using the helper. What I want is to not load the whole video. I just want to load the first frame of the video and use that frame as a poster. I have a a lot of videos on the page and they take a lot of time in loading.